# Can't install Wordpress after changing Apache DocumentRoot

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache, ubuntu

I just changed my DocumentRoot from my Apache, creating another default file (instead of changing 000-default.conf) named mysite.conf. I changed from /var/www/html to /home/user/projects.

This new root is working fine. I'm trying to do a fresh Wordpress install in this directory, so I moved the Wordpress files in there, but when I try to access my localhost, it says: "Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress."

I already uncommented the msql.so extensions in my php.ini. Restarted Apache, and still get the error. Also tried to re-install PHP5 and mySQL. Already checked if mySQL is running (for some reason, it only shows it it's running if I sudo). I'm using Ubuntu 14.04LTS.

Answer (score 2):

Just solved the problem. After tons of "fixes", this is what solved my problem:

Open your apache2 conf file: sudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
Edit the following section:

Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted

And change "/etc/www/html" for your new DocumentRoot.